# Give class to first td , but some table rows have a td rowspan

Tags: jquery

I'm twisting my brains to get this to work , and need some help please

I have a table that i need to add some classes to the first td cell , but some of the tablerows have a td rowspan and when i try to add a class to first of type ofc it applies to every td in each row

Here is example HTML

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" valign="middle"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is what i'd like to do using jQuery

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3" class="first"></td>
      <td class="second"></td>
      <td class="third"></td>
      <td class="fourth"></td>
      <td class="fifth"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="second"></td>
      <td class="third"></td>
      <td class="fourth"></td>
      <td class="fifth"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="second"></td>
      <td class="third"></td>
      <td class="fourth"></td>
      <td class="fifth"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr">
      <td class="first"></td>
      <td class="second"></td>
      <td class="third"></td>
      <td class="fourth"></td>
      <td class="fifth"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You will have to write some code to solve this... Check if a table has rowspan, and then skip that number of rows when you add the `first` class to the first cell in these rows

Comment: i said what i've tried , i've used jQuery to apply a class to the first-child

Comment: jQuery('td:first-child').addClass('first');

Comment: That REALLY looks like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this jquery code to find and update the class depending on the eq number will set the class you want to the td by number

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#table").find('tr').each(function(){
        var td = $(this).children('td').eq(1); //the selected td in every row 
            td.addClass('class you want to add');
    });
   });
```

Comment: this does nothing i need to have done , just adds a class to the td based on eq  , does not differentiate between the colspan. Thanks